# Making a Circular Barplot in 'R'

Tags: r

I'm trying to recreate this circular barplot:

[image]

The only difference would be the data, labels and the fact that I want 160 bars on my chart. I have looked at the code in R Graph Gallery but I am a complete novice and don't understand how to go from what they have to what I want.

Any help in making this barplot or pointing me somewhere that can help me would be greatly appreciated

This is the [Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxaAX.png) It shows Gross Value Added per hour (£)

Answer (score 4):

The problem with this kind of question is that, without seeing your data, it is next to impossible to show a solution that you can get working with your own data set. It's certainly possible to create a visualization like this with 160 bars, as I can show with some dummy data:

```r
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(x = as.factor(1:160), y = sort(runif(160))/2 + 0.5,
                 group = as.factor(sample(5, 160, TRUE)))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = group)) + 
  geom_col(width = 0.5) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.25, color = "#0b192d", size = 0.1) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.5, color = "#0b192d", size = 0.1) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.75, color = "#0b192d", size = 0.1) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.5, 1)) +
  geom_text(label = "Average\nWorking Week\n(Hours)",
            x = 0, y = 0, color = "white", vjust = 1.7, size = 5,
            check_overlap = TRUE, fontface = "bold") +
  coord_polar() +
  theme_dark() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#6a4199", "#ea5f3c", "#f69a40", 
                               "#2dbed3", "#ef0000")) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#0b192d"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "white", size = 4),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none",
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#0b192d"),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

One of the problems as you can see is that to fit 160 bars around this kind of plot, the text labels have to be tiny, and therefore unreadable unless you are going to print this on a very large (A2 or larger) poster.

---

**EDIT**

Now we have (a picture of) the data, we can have a reproducible example:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(City, pound, fill = pound)) + 
  geom_col(width = 0.5) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 20, color = "#0b192d", size = 0.1) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 30, color = "#0b192d", size = 0.1) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 40, color = "#0b192d", size = 0.1) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-20, 50)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c("red", "gold", "forestgreen")) +
  geom_text(label = "Gross\nValue Added\nper Hour",
            x = 0, y = 0, color = "white", vjust = 1.7, size = 5,
            check_overlap = TRUE, fontface = "bold") +
  coord_polar() +
  theme_dark() +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#0b192d"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "white", size = 7,
                                   angle = 90 + 180 / pi * seq(85/43 * pi, 
                                       0 * pi, length.out = 43)),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none",
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#0b192d"),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

**Data**

```r
df <- structure(list(City = c("London", "Birmingham", "Glasgow City", 
"Liverpool", "Bristol, City of", "Manchester", "Sheffield", "Leeds", 
"City of Edinburgh", "Leicester", "Derby", "Nottingham", "Coventry", 
"Bradford", "Cardiff and Vale of Glamorgan", "Swansea", "Aberdeen City and Aberdeenshire", 
"Kingston upon Hull, City of", "Stoke-on-Trent", "Portsmouth", 
"Southampton", "Brighton and Hove", "Plymouth", "Luton", "Bedford", 
"o verhampton", "Aberdeen Ct., and Aberdeenshire", "Bournemouth, Christchurch and Pooh", 
"Norwich and East Norfolk", "Peterborough", "Cambridgeshire CC", 
"Milton Keynes", "Southend-on-Sea", "Sunder and", "Warrington", 
"York", "Bournemouth, Christchurch and Pooh", "Ipswich", "Telford and Wrekin", 
"Angus and Dundee City", "Gloucestershire", "Blackpool", "Durham CC"
), pound = c(46.4, 30.6, 31.1, 29.9, 31, 33.4, 29.9, 33.4, 41.9, 
31, 31.8, 30.8, 36.2, 27.6, 31.8, 30.8, 35.4, 28.2, 29, 34.4, 
40.3, 33.9, 30.2, 36.3, 31.3, 27.9, 35.4, 31.7, 30.5, 34.2, 33.4, 
43.9, 25.2, 36.3, 32.5, 34.6, 31.7, 33.3, 30.8, 31.2, 33.6, 27.1, 
29)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -43L))
```

Comment: I changed the data from 160 to 44 and edited it into the original post. Would I just need to edit what you posted with the new number?

Comment: @Alex no, that is just me creating the dummy data frame. Don't do that. You have not posted your data in the question. You have posted a _picture_ of your data. I would have to sit and transcribe this to get you a working solution, and life's too short. To get the data into your question, go to your R console, type `dput(my_data_frame)` (where obviously you change `my_data_frame` to whatever your data frame is called), then copy and paste the output into a code block in your question.

Comment: @Alex see my update. Just call your data frame `df` and this code should work for you